# Swift: reproducing forEach, viewing source code?

Tags: swift, closures

I am currently learning closures and I think I have it but I am interested in reproducing the forEach method of an array. I would like to see how its done. In xcode I can see the declaration which shows

```
    @inlinable public func forEach(_ body: (Element) throws -> Void) rethrows
```

but what i really want to see is the actually code.

For example the following

```
var items = [1,2,3]
items.forEach { (item) in
    print(item)
}
```

I am interested in how the closure has access to (item), how is forEach providing this information.

The closure is my code and it receives the first variable which I have named "item", of course it works but i wanted to know how.

If I wanted to create a new version of forEach, lets call it forEachNew then how would i do this.

Is the forEach an extension over a specific type/ protocol ?

Any help really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Search for `forEach` [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the current implementation of [`Sequence.forEach`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/51bbaebd0895c25ad23c2c51eedb0b2ee0ca0206/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift#L714) on GitHub, since Swift is open-source.

The current implementation simply uses a `for ... in` loop to iterate through the `Sequence` and then executes the `body` closure for each element.

```
@inlinable
  public func forEach(
    _ body: (Element) throws -> Void
  ) rethrows {
    for element in self {
      try body(element)
    }
  }
}
```